# Probability that two sets intersect

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be two sets, each containing m elements. Let's say that an element is an integer chosen randomly from {1, 2, ..., n-1, n}, and there can be duplicate elements in X and Y (i.e., same integer can appear twice or more). What is the probability that X and Y are disjoint (i.e., no integer appears both in X and Y)?

Comment: Do we have a model of how numbers end up in $X$, possibly more than once. One model, among many, is that we put numbers into multiset $X$ by sampling $m$ times, with replacement.

Comment: Numbers in X and Y are sampled uniformly at random from the range [1, n]. So yes, to build X and Y you'd sample from {1, 2, ..., n} $m$ times, with replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to split it into cases where $X$ has $i$ types of elements. For each case you have ${n \choose i}{m-1 \choose m-i}{m+n-i-1 \choose m}$ ways to put in the integers while keeping them disjoint.

(the factors are respectively:

1. ways to choose the $i$ integers used to fill $X$;
2. ways to fill $X$ with $i$ integers (put $i$ integers into $m$ slots) such that all integers are used for at least once;
3. ways to fill $Y$ with $n-i$ integers (put $n-i$ integers into $m$ slots) but no condition on the least number of occurence)

Thus, the probability is $$\frac{\textrm{number of desired cases}}{\textrm{number of all cases}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{n \choose i}{m-1 \choose m-i}{m+n-i-1 \choose m}}{{m+n-1 \choose m}^2}.$$

I'm not sure if the summation can be simplified.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer! But why should we fill X in a way that all integers are used at least once? It's possible that n >> m. Plus, X should have exactly m integers. And also Y can be filled with any integers, independent of what X has. (The only condition is, it has to contain m integers.)

Comment: All the $i$ integers, not all $n$ integers

Comment: Basically I am dividing it into cases that are mutually exclusive. So an $X$ that only have $(a,b,c)$ ($i=3$) is certainly distinct from an $X$ that only have $(a, b, c, d)$ ($i=4$).